# How to get the file format of an image shape in powerpoit using interop

Tags: c#, image, interop, powerpoint

I need to get all the GIF pictures inside of a PowerPoint presentation (2007 and 2010) using interop and c#, but the shape.PictureFormat.GetType() does not contain any useful information, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user adds an image the original file name (with extension) is saved by default into shape "alt text" (right click on shape /size and position / alternative text).

But the user can change it, so for some images you could haven't the data.

Instead, if you have control over image inserting you could store that information into a specific shape.tag property and then read it later.